# How to generate new Breed NFT Image?

Tags: web3js, nft, solana

How do I use two NFT images to create a new NFT through breeding?

I'm a bit confused about this. I've used different attributes for coverage. now I want to generate the image as well.

For example, if the male parent is a black horse and the female parent is a white horse, the newly generated horse should be similar to this. How can I create an image like that?

Comment: Take a look at CryptoKitties contract. They do something like that.